# How can I speedup external function in Firebird UDF?

Tags: firebird, user-defined-functions

Even simple udf which just return an constant integer is much slower in query than any builtin function.

Comment: compare PLANs of both queries. Most probably it is because your external function is a total black box to Firebird precluding query transformations, and some built-in functions are intimately known by SQL optimizer, so the query gets changed a lot.

Comment: You might be right with query plan. So I tried UDF in a while do loop in execute block. A do-nothing external UDF is almost ten times slower than cos function.

Comment: Consider using Firebird 3 and [PSQL stored functions](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-psql-funcs.html) instead. There is probably no way to improve this, UDFs require Firebird to 'break out' its normal execution mode to call on the external library. This has some overhead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel for example FB engine might know cosine being "pure function", so can be executed in parallel threads on SMP machines. Also I think I heard FB3 tried to introduce some kind of limited UDF sandboxing, trying to protect at least against some crashes in those functions, but maybe It is false memory

Comment: I tried this on Firebird 3 at the first place. PSQL wont help because I need access to shared memory from another application.

Comment: Then I suggest you ask on the firebird-devel mailinglist. But, I think there is not much that can be done to improve performance. Maybe moving to a UDR might help, but I think that will suffer from similar overhead.

Comment: I'd suggest that "other application" would insert its relevant data into Firebird tables, and Firebird SQL only works in SQL realm